# How to integrate two models in sequential order in one endpoint?

Tags: python, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I want to create an API using one endpoint but in my app, the first model output is the second model output. Is it possible to implement using SageMaker?

[image]

From my understanding `model_fn`, `prediction_fn`, `output_fn` can only use one model at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pipeline Model (sequential models)

There is a specific mode in SageMaker:
Look at [PipelineModel](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/pipeline.html).

> You can pass a list of sagemaker.Model objects in the order you want
> the inference to happen.

This is an official AWS example to follow:
[Train register and deploy a pipeline model](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-pipelines/tabular/train-register-deploy-pipeline-model/train%20register%20and%20deploy%20a%20pipeline%20model.ipynb)

```py
from sagemaker import PipelineModel

pipeline_model = PipelineModel(
    models=[model_0, model_1, ...],
    role=role,
    sagemaker_session=pipeline_session
)
```

It works like a normal SageMaker Model, in fact you have the normal [deployment method](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/pipeline.html#sagemaker.pipeline.PipelineModel.deploy).

You can also follow this [guide](https://dev.to/aws-builders/deploying-the-xgboost-model-to-aws-from-locally-developed-artifacts-adding-inference-pipeline-fa5) that show how to deploy an Xgboost model binary built for a developer, where a post-processing layer is added through an inference pipeline in sagemaker, deploying an endpoint.